# Scatter plot change colors of points

Tags: plotting

I am currently trying to visualize a scatter plot given x and y-axis from the table Data and the colors of the points I want to come from the table valuesnew.

```
Data = {{0.458363,0.638569},{0.853902,0.756263},{0.880396,0.411021},{0.112152,0.618945}}
valuesnew = {Red, Red, Yellow, Blue}
ListPlot[Transpose[{Data[[All,1]], Data[[All,2]]}], PlotStyle->valuesnew]
```

The problem is that it colors all the points only based on the last color of the list. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: `ListPlot[Map[List, Data], PlotStyle -> valuesnew]`

Comment: `ListPlot[List /@ Transpose[{Data[[All, 1]], Data[[All, 2]]}], PlotStyle -> valuesnew]`. The `Yellow` point is hard to see,

Comment: @LouisB it works thank you very much!

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi also this approach works thank you very much! Yes you are correct I changed yellow to another color since I couldn't see it.

Comment: try also `ListPlot[Thread@Style[Data, valuesnew]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`PointValuePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointValuePlot.html). `PointValuePlot` is marked as experimental in version 12.2 so its functionality may change.

With `data` and `valuesnew` in OP, then

```
PointValuePlot[data -> valuesnew]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.